# How to install as86 in debian 6.0?

Tags: debian, as86

I need to install as86 in debian 6.0. However, I cannot find as86 in debian-6.0-DVD.then,where to find as86 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you try to find a package on DVD by looking at file names, it's time to try `apt-cache search` instead:

```
# apt-cache search as86
bin86 - 16-bit x86 assembler and loader
```

Now we know it's in `bin86` package, and we do:

```
# apt-get install bin86
```